# Wordpress and Symfony on the same machine

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, symfony

this is an easy one.

I have a machine (on Digital Ocean) with:

- a symfony site
- a wordpress installation
- phpmymadmin

The symfony site is the entry point, on 80 port. Everything is working fine.

I set PMA is on 8888 port, and its ok.

The problem is with my wordpress installation....I want to install it separately from the symfony app, on a different port if is possibible.

This is my conf file:

```
server {
    listen 8082;
    root /var/www/html/templates/xxxxxx;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name xxxxx xxxxx xxxx;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
          root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

}
```

When I point to my site:8082, the server gives me back to symfony site on 80 port.

What's wrong???

Thank you guys

Comment: Have you configured SITEURL and HOME in WordPress general settings or `wp-config.php`?

Comment: Did you try to find any answer? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/multiple-domains-on-different-ports-of-the-same-droplet

Comment: Yes! ... I missed to update my HOME and SITEURL with the new url in database! ... now it works fine, thanks!